# qmake generate a single vcxproj for x86 and x64?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qmake

we're using qmake and *.pro files to generate Visual Studio project files, currently 2 files one for x86 and one for x64. To achieve this we're using a script which first sets the environment variables (e.g. %QTDIR%) for x86, calls qmake after that to generate x86 *.vcxproj and repeat that for x64 (set and call).

```
setEnvVariables("x86")
cmd /c "$env:QTDIR\bin\qmake" -Wall -tp vc -o "myProj.vcxproj" myProj.pro

setEnvVariables("x64")
cmd /c "$env:QTDIR\bin\qmake" -Wall -tp vc -o "myProj_$platformextension.vcxproj" myProj.pro
```

We've different lib/include paths for Qt x86 and x64 (Qt4.8.7 and Qt4.8.7_x64).

My question now: Is there a way to force qmake to generate a single project file for both platforms so we can use MSBUILD on a single project file? E.g. `msbuild myProj.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64`  and next step `msbuild myProj.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x86`.

Could I archieve this with special *.pro and *.pri setup?

Comment: Well the code to set env-vars and to call qmake is powershell if anybody needs to know that

Comment: We build 32bit and 64bit for all msvc versions just using Qt Creator and a single pro file, and without going through vcxproj. So what is the reason you want to use these msvc project files?

Comment: we're using tfs buildserver thats the reason here

Comment: We have the same need. We have developers that want to launch/debug Qt projects (Debug->Start new instance...) within the same solution where they are debugging other non-Qt applications. So, we have <proj> and <proj>32 vcxproj files. However, I have not figured out all the guts of your "setEnvVariables" functions, so we run one qmake -tp vc within the x86 command prompt, and another within the normal (64-bit) command prompt. I'd like to simplify/merge all of this. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @e-holder it's bin a while since i asked that so I can't remember 100%. However I still have this old Powershell script and the setVariable function is just sets environment variable needed for qt. So the code snippet is part of a larger powershell script which generates a vcxproj files for every qt version and platform available e.g. `myproject_x64_qt477.vcxproj` or `myproject_x86_qt561.vcxproj` and so on. So i just had to double click the project and version i needed

Comment: @e-holder it seems like i've never found a solution to make a single vcxproj for all platforms

Comment: Okay. Thanks for responding! I was able to write one script to generate my two vcxproj files (no longer have to use the x86 command prompt), but I haven't figured out how to make it create one vcxproj file that can generate both 32 and 64 bit libraries.

Comment: @e-holder thats what i said, i've never ever found a way to generate a single vcxproj for 32 and 64 always have to use multiple vcxprojs. I guess its not possible for now